# Trouble adding Foreign Key Constraint (error ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list)

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, alter

I am learning how to create a small and simple database for class with Primary Key and Foreign Key restraints.  I am getting ORA-02770 when attempting to run my ALTER TABLE statement, which as I understand is notifying me that the column I am referencing in the outside table is not listed as a primary key constraint.  However, from what I can see my syntax is correct naming the primary keys in my CREATE TABLES statements.  I searched inside the all_cons_columns table for the player_info table and it showed the primary keys listed as well.  Could I get some guidance?  Listed below is my current script:

```
CREATE TABLE Player_Game
( school varchar2(30),
  player_number number(2,0),
  game_number number(1,0), 

  CONSTRAINT playergame_pk PRIMARY KEY (school, player_number,game_number)
);

CREATE TABLE School 
( school varchar2(30), 
  city varchar2(30), 
  coach varchar2(30), 
  team_name varchar2(30),
  win_record number (2,0), 
  loss_record number (2,0), 

  CONSTRAINT school_pk PRIMARY KEY (school)
);

CREATE TABLE Game 
( school varchar2(30),
  game_number number(1,0), 
  game_date DATE, 
  game_score varchar2(15), 

  CONSTRAINT game_pk PRIMARY KEY (school, game_number)
);

CREATE TABLE player_info
( school varchar2(30), 
  player_number number(2,0), 
  player_name varchar2(25), 

 CONSTRAINT playerinfo_pk PRIMARY KEY (school, player_number)
);

CREATE TABLE city 
( city varchar2(30),
  population number(5,0),

 CONSTRAINT city_pk PRIMARY KEY (city)
);

/*Here is the failing alter command */
ALTER TABLE Player_Game
ADD CONSTRAINT playergame_fk FOREIGN KEY (school) REFERENCES game(school);
```

Comment: As the error suggests, your `playergame_fk` column list doesn't match any primary or unique key on the `game` table. Specifically, your primary key is defined as a composite of `school` and `game_number`. A foreign key must match the column list exactly to work.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you Chris.  I'm from Northern Utah as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect column list in `playergame_fk` in the alter table statement. The **column list of the foreign key** must exactly match with the **column list of the primary key it is referencing to**.

Primary Key column list is `school, game_number`, therefore, your foreign key must have the same columns:

```
ALTER TABLE Player_Game
ADD CONSTRAINT playergame_fk FOREIGN KEY (school, game_number) 
  REFERENCES game(school, game_number);
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you Lalit! That worked perfectly for me and it makes sense as well.

Comment: @stasis100t You're welcome! Please mark it as answered, would help others too.